# Enable Layered navigation and show only subcategories in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories, layered-navigation

I have to use **Layered navigation** in `Magento` site.

**My category structure is:**

```
Mobile
  Nokia
  Motorola
  Micromax
Accessories
  Memory Card
  Screen Guard
  Flip Cover
```

For a particular category say `Mobile` I change `Is Anchor to YES`.Then the filter options are visible. But this shows full categories in right side. For a category say `Accessories` I make `Is Anchor to NO.` Then the filter options are not available and it shows subcategories only in left side.

My requirement is **I have to enable Layered navigation**(show filterable attributes) **and show only subcategories**.

How can I did this?? I am using **Magento 1.9.0.1**

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Just read it carefully buddy. What I getting is when I click a category item I am getting all the sub-category items listed , but I need to show only the sub-category of that particular category only. Hope you got it!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Layered Navigation and display the subcategories only if any in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316565/use-layered-navigation-and-display-the-subcategories-only-if-any-in-magento)

Comment: @fantasticrice yah right. But there is no answer!!

Comment: @next2u - you should only post one question per issue.